# FFMPEG disjoin/separating/uncoupling of MP3 album file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, concatenation, audacity

I have an single MP3 album file that has when loaded in a player multiple tracks with artist and title.

In FFMPEG there is an option to [concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) media files. What I'm looking for is to split this into separate tracks with the title and artist metadata if possible.

So far I was only able to find this option in Audacity which requires [manually](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/creating_and_selecting_labels.html) [splitting](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/export_multiple.html) each segment. Sadly this album doesn't have enough [silent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264779/how-to-split-an-mp3-file-by-detecting-silent-parts) parts between tracks.

Preferable to extract the track list with artist name, title and the duration of each track; then extract each track separately.

Comment: Do you have the .cue file?

Comment: Yes, I do have a .cue file! Thanks!